# iOS: MFMailComposeViewController not working on model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Having trouble with the MFMessageComposeViewController.
The situation goes like this:

I am creating a model that will implement the MFMessageComposeViewController instead of doing it in the ViewController directly. Now, when I implement the presentModalViewController:: method, it works fine (the mail.app interface appears) but when I click the cancel / send button in the mail.app interface, it will not dismiss the mail.app..

Its like something like this:

a method snippet from MSGViewController that implements the send mail model:

```
- (IBAction)openEmail:(id)sender {
    Messaging *mail = [[Messaging alloc]initWithModal:self];
    [mail emailInvitation:@"Eventz Date" eventAt:@"Eventz Location" withImage:nil];
    [self.sendingStatus setText:mail.sendingStatus];
}
```

my model for implementing the Messaging:

Messaging.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface Messaging : NSObject <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *sendingStatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id modal;

- (id)initWithModal:(id)modal;
- (void)emailInvitation:(NSString *)eventDate eventAt:(NSString *)eventLocation withImage:(UIImage *)imageAttachment;

@end
```

Messaging.m

```
#import "Messaging.h"

@implementation Messaging

@synthesize sendingStatus = _sendingStatus;
@synthesize modal = _modal;

- (id)initWithModal:(id)modal{
    self = [super init];
    self.modal = modal;
    return self;
}



- (void)emailInvitation:(NSString *)eventDate eventAt:(NSString *)eventLocation withImage:(UIImage *)imageAttachment{

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){      
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Event Invitation"];
        [mailer setMessageBody:@"message body"] isHTML:NO];

        if(imageAttachment != nil){
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageAttachment);
            [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"imageFileName"];
        }

        [self.modal presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    [self deviceDoNotSupportMessaging];        
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sending cancelled.";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail saved.";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sent.";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sending failed.";
            break;
        default:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail not sent.";
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

BTW, the NSLog(@"called"); in the .m is not called actually...
Can someone have any suggestion? thanks.. :D

Comment: the viewcontroller that implements the model.. it goes like this: Messaging *mail = [[Messaging alloc]initWithModal:self];

Comment: so that the message interface will appear on the MSGViewController..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am wondering why you aren't getting an error when your pointer get dealloc'd.  I used your code and got that error right away when instantiating the Message class:

```
Messaging *mail = [[Messaging alloc]initWithModal:self];
```

So I changed one thing, I made mail a Strong Property in my calling class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Messaging *mail;
```

And then called it this way:

```
mail = [[Messaging alloc]initWithModal:self];
                [mail emailInvitation:@"Eventz Date" eventAt:@"Eventz Location" withImage:nil];
                NSLog(@"Called the emailInvitation");
```

The log statements were called and I even made sure that the MailComposer got back the proper response:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sending cancelled.";
            NSLog(@"Mail Cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail saved.";
            NSLog(@"Mail Saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sent.";
            NSLog(@"Mail Sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail sending failed.";
            NSLog(@"Mail Failed");
            break;
        default:
            self.sendingStatus = @"Mail not sent.";
            NSLog(@"Mail Not Sent");
            break;
    }

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And it did.

BTW - I love the way you are doing this.  This is the way OOP should be done.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
[self.modal dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

instead of `[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: thanks,. I have also tried it but still does not work.. even the NSLog(@"called"); within the didFinishWithResult method is also not called.. i mean the entire didFinishWithResult is not called actually...

Comment: try to declare  Messaging *mail as global in h file.

Comment: If your put your mail code in the MSGViewController and set the delegate of the mail to the MSGViewController is working? Because I can not see something wrong in your code. And also try to clean the project

Comment: yeah.. its working when the code is in the MSGViewController. However, if I want to implement it in other projects, I need to implement to delegate as well also.. hmmm.. thanks Terente.. :D